# Fields Not Being Indexed in Lucene

Tags: lucene, indexing

I'm working with Sitecore 8.1. I have `<indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>` in the `<documentOptions>` node of the `DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` file. When I open the index up in Luke and navigate to a document that I expect certain fields for, those fields are not present. It seems that only some base Sitecore fields are being stored, none of the template-specific ones.

I tried adding `<indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>` to the root of `<defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration>` as well, as I know that's the location it was in for previous versions of Sitecore. That didn't help either.

I'm specifically looking in `sitecore_master_index` right now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The fields are being indexed, but they are not all marked as `storageType="YES"` in the `default Lucene configuration`. This means that the fields will be tokenized in the index, but not stored, or visible in Luke. Note that they are *still* searchable even tho they are not stored.

If you want to be able to see the values in Luke, you will need to change the `storageType` to `"YES"` in the `raw:AddFieldByFieldTypeName` section.

**Example below:**

```xml
  <fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldTypeName">
    <fieldType fieldTypeName="attachment" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
     <!-- others removed for brevity -->
  </fieldTypes>
</fieldMap>
```

**Note:** Doing this will dramatically increase the size of your index and could potentially affect performance.